# Disable multiple login with same user in spring boot and OAuth2 application

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, netflix-zuul

I have microservice architecture application working with zuul api-gateway added with Oauth2 security feature. Now, I can able to login with same user in multiple session(I mean multiple browser and multiple machine). So I want to restrict multiple login of same user.

I used below code to restrict same user login. This code works perfectly when I'm doing oauth logout. But I'm facing problem when user logged in and close their browser or clear their browser cookies.

```
static SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;

@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login", "/logout").permitAll().anyRequest()
        .authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
        .failureHandler(loginAuthenticationFailureHandler).permitAll().and().logout().and().authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .maximumSessions(1)
        .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
        .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry);
    }

 @Bean
    public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher> httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher>(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
    }
```

Can any one help me how to implement this single user session logout when browser close and cookie clear or is there any separate procedure to develop this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to make an implementation using this same approach to use the sessionManagement configuration, but it didn't work for me, in my case I was just needing to remove the multiple login, make either the new login go off or the previous login, do this with an extension of InMemoryTokenStore.

```
@Component
public class ResetTokenStore extends InMemoryTokenStore {

 @Override
 public OAuth2AccessToken getAccessToken(OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
    OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = super.getAccessToken(authentication);

    if(accessToken != null) {
        removeAccessToken(accessToken);
        removeRefreshToken(accessToken.getRefreshToken());
    }

    return null;
 }
}
```

Basically what I do is force the token renewal, every time a new token is generated and logged in, and the previously generated accesstoken and refreshtoken are deleted.

In the class that extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
    endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore())
            .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
            .reuseRefreshTokens(false)
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}

@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new ResetTokenStore();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have used JDBC session management and window close event to logout user when he/she close browser window.

Comment: You're welcome, now I'm using that same approach using RedisTokenStore and it's working too.